# import csv to mysql without load data infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have to import a csv to a mysql database
I can't use load data infile because it's disabled on the webserver.

are there any other ways to do so?

Comment: Sure, open the file, read the contents, and insert each line.

Comment: There are several ways : through server-side code, doing it yourself manually, hire a bunch of slaves to do it manually, ... what kind of solution are you thinking of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scripting language available, you can loop through the CSV lines and have it generate SQL code:

PHP example:

```
<?php

$lines = file('file.csv');

foreach($lines as $line){
    //sepatates each cell by the delimiter "," (watch for delimiters in the cell, escaped or not)
    $cell = explode(",",$line);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (";
    $sql.= "'".$cell[0]."','".$cell[1]."','".$cell[2]."');";

    echo $sql;

}

?>
```

Comment: Better to use a prepared query. This will fail if any of your columns include double quotes (or other characters) that should be escaped before sending to the db server.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the file and insert using a prepared query. Prepared querys should be quicker too, since the DB doesn't have to recompile every SQL string you send it. That will be more noticeable when you have thousands and thousands of lines.

```
<?php
// assume $db is a PDO connection
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');

// read file contents to an array
$lines = file('file.csv');

// insert each line
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // see manual to specify $delimter, $enclousure, or $more
    $cols = str_getcsv($lines);
    $stmt->execute($cols);
}
```

That'll work. Since we're using `file()`, the script can consume a lot of memory if your CSV file is HUGE. To make better use of resources, do the following to keep only one line in memory at a time:

```
<?php
// assume $db is a PDO connection
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while ($cols = fgetcsv($handle)) {
  $stmt->execute($cols);
}
```